# Oracle Preparations

Tags: oracle10g

I am new to oracle.can anyone tell me the books and web sites suitable to learn oracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle manual:
http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/portal.all_books

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/index.html